# Efeito de Timeline

Tags: html5, css3

Gostaria de saber se existe algum plugin para o efeito igual o desse site aqui:

http://www.popupdesign.com.br/servicos/

Na parte de como funciona, tem uma espécie de régua vertical.

Comment: Você quis dizer um efeito tipo timeline? Isso aqui pode te ajudar: http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/

Comment: ss rs nao sabia como abrir o topico rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: Pegando um gancho... Encontrei aqui no site um tópico sobre determinado efeito. É um de porcentagem em uma esfera. Tipo uma pizza que quando a página é carregada ela só completa determinada porcentagem. Por exemplo, 80%, a pizza não fecha 100%, vai até 80%, mas é com efeito. Alguém lembra ?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft poste seu comentário como resposta para o Autor da pergunta marcar-la como resposta e fechar este assunto ;)

Comment: Você quis dizer um efeito tipo `timeline`? Este tópico pode ajudar você: [Vertical Timeline](http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/)

Comment: @Kirito Gosto dessa abordagem de usabilidade e navegabilidade, em meu projeto usei a mesma pegada, só que não tenho dependências de Framework, Library ou pluguin. Fiz em javaScript puro e CSS3. E quanto ao grafico de percentual que o  menciona, tente usar Canvas fiz um teste e deu certo mas em meu projeto usei outra abordagem para criar esse efeito, claro sem pluguin até porque não gosto de usar jQuery só pra efeito de transição e tal! rsrsr

Comment: @Kirito Mas segue uns links interessantes pra quem curtir modo mamãe js.Pluguins:scroll:http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/ http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/ Graficos percent: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/                   http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/

Comment: @Kirito Use somente code open source, tome cuidado para não usar código proprietário, só um toque tá! Rs.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, na época que no NinjA fez o comentário talvez vc não soubesse como o site funciona.... rola de publicar a resposta agora ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

efeito bem simples pode ser feito com : https://github.com/matthieua/WOW e https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

WoW js ele faz animacoes acontecerem quando voce da um scrool na pagina.

Basicamente esse efeito pode ser feito usando : fadeInRight do animate.css

exemplo:

```
<h1 class="animated infinite fadeInRight">Example</h1>
```

espero ter ajudado.